# Is it possible to Chromecast a Google+ video from Android?

Tags: google-plus, chromecast

I'm trying to Chromecast a video uploaded to Google+, using my Android phone (Sony Xperia Z). I thought this would be pretty straightforward, as video is already on the net, and it seems the Chromecast has a pretty simple way to just be forwarded an URL and playing it. However, no Chromecast symbol appears when clicking the video in the Google+ app. Anyone knows if this functionality exists or not in the Google+ app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality magically appeared in the google plus app on android last week, so now problem is solved. The Chromecast icon now appears when on the net with a chromecast device.

Answer (score 1):

Chromecast support does not currently exist in Google plus.

If you would like to cast the video, try going to G+ in the chrome beta and opening the video in full screen. The chrome beta has support for casting some videos from the browser.